# less.render returning object not string

Tags: node.js, less

I'm trying to write a simple node module that compiles less files.

In less version 2.0.0 [docs](http://lesscss.org/usage/#programmatic-usage) the example is very simple yet I don't get the results I'm expecting, here's my test code:

```
var less_css = "@background: #000; body{background:@background;}";

less.render(less_css)
.then(function(css) {
    console.log(css);
},
function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

The logged output:

```
{ css: 'body {\n  background: #000000;\n}\n' }
```

As you can see it's halfway there with this object, but I was expecting a string that I could write to a file.
Maybe there's some options I need to pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write `css.css` to your file:

```
var less = require("./lib/less-node"),
fs = require('fs'),
less_css = "@background: #000; body{background:@background;}";

less.render(less_css)
.then(function(css) {
fs.writeFile("style.css", css.css, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }
});
},
function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

And than `cat style.css` will give:

```
body {
  background: #000000;
}
```

**with options**

You can set the options for compiling as an second argument for the `render()` function:

```
var less = require("./lib/less-node"),
fs = require('fs'),
less_css = "@background: #000; body{background:@background;}";
var options = {};
options.compress = false;
options.sourceMap = true;
less.render(less_css,options)
.then(function(css) {
fs.writeFile("style.css", css.css, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("The css file was saved!");
    }
});
fs.writeFile("style.css.map", css.map, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("The source map file was saved!");
    }
});
},
function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

You can use the above to create a source map file, `cat style.css.map` will give now:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["input"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAmB;EAAK,mBAAA"}
```

Notice that you can inspect the https://raw.githubusercontent.com/less/less.js/master/bin/lessc file to find more examaples

**update**

> So after reading the source in the link I tried passing
>   'sourceMapFileInline: true' to the render function but it had no
>   effect.

Afterwards the solution for this is pretty simple. You should set the sourcemap option as keys of the sourcemap option which so should an object to.

```
options.sourceMap = {sourceMapFileInline: true};
```

or indeed:

```
less.render(less_css,{sourceMap: { sourceMapFileInline: true}})
```

When inspection the source code it seems that the `sourceMapFileInline` is not taken in account in the current version of Less. I'm not sure if this is intend.

Because the `sourceMap` option does works and generates `css.map` in the resulting object you can generate the inline sourcemap code yourself:

```
// Create Base64 Object
var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}


var options = {};
options.sourceMap = true;
less.render(less_css,options)
.then(function(css) {
var withmap = css.css + "\n" + "/*# sourceMappingURL=\"data:application/json;base64," +  Base64.encode(css.map)+"\"";

fs.writeFile("style.css", withmap, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("The css file was saved!");
    }
});
```

Base64 encoding from: https://gist.github.com/ncerminara/11257943#file-base64-js

Comment: Awesome! worked first time, thanks for the help. Now I just need to get sourceMaps working.

Comment: So after reading the source in the link I tried passing 'sourceMapFileInline: true' to the render function but it had no effect. What is the correct way to get inline source-maps embedded in the css? Thanks.

Comment: You should create an option object and pass that into the `less.render()` function. `var options = {}; options.sourceMap = true; options.sourceMapFileInline = true;` and than `less.render(less_css,options)`

Comment: Thanks again for the swift reply. Yeah, that's what I tried, except I didn't create the object before hand, so I had `less.render(less_css,{sourceMap: true, sourceMapFileInline: true})`
Not sure if creating the options object inline makes any difference?

Comment: Thanks Bass, but still no luck. Seems others are struggling too https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2301

Comment: For anyone else reading through this question the update section of Bass's answer now has the correct methods for creating inline source maps with less 2.0.0 `less.render(less_css,{sourceMap: { sourceMapFileInline: true}})`